# I have functional problem but I cannot see where

Tags: python

I know this is not good to ask this kind of question but I am honest and this is my problem now. I do not know that to do anymore so I have to ask this (also I do not know where else I can ask this). I cannot debug my code that I can see when day changes so I do not know where the problem is.

My code is taking pictures and sending them to twitter between 24 hours. **Code is working fine at the first day but after that it is not sending photos anymore.** And I do not see any problems in my code. Please take a look and say if you see problem.

```
from twython import Twython
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep
import datetime
import os
sleep(500)

camera = PiCamera()
camera.rotation = 180
datetimeNow = datetime.datetime.now()
oldDate = 0
newDate = 0
photoAlreadyTaken = 0

CONSUMER_KEY = 'sad...'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'asd...'
ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY = 'fdsf...'
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 'asd..'

twitter = Twython(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, 
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

while True:
    try:
        newDate = datetimeNow.day
    except:
        print("error")  
    if newDate != oldDate:
        if datetimeNow.hour == 14 and photoAlreadyTaken != 1:   
            photoAlreadyTaken = 1
            try:
                camera.start_preview()
                sleep(5)
                camera.capture('/home/pi/strawberry.jpg')
                camera.stop_preview()
            except:
                photoAlreadyTaken = 0

            sleep(5)

            try:
                with open('/home/pi/strawberry.jpg', 'rb') as photo:
                twitter.update_status_with_media(status=str(datetimeNow.day) + "-" + str(datetimeNow.month) + "-" + str(datetimeNow.year), media=photo)
            except:
                photoAlreadyTaken = 0

            oldDate = datetimeNow.day

    else:    #When the first photo is sent this is executed, but I cannot debug how long
        photoAlreadyTaken = 0
    sleep(500)
```

Comment: You never change `datetimeNow` in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first cycle of the loop, both newDate and oldDate equal datetime.datetime.now() at the time of script activation forever.

Your reasoning about the value of datetimeNow is a bit off; it's set at activation and you never update it. Consider replacing datetimeNow (static value) with datetime.datetime.now() (function invocation that gives the current date-time); or at least update datetimeNow somewhere inside the loop.

Good luck!